# How I can avoid requesting Basic Authentication when HTTP method is OPTIONS on Apache .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, cross-domain, preflight

I am using HTTP basic authentication (username & password) in a site including API endpoints  hosted in Apache, I am doing something like this on .htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic 
AuthName "Restricted Files"
# (Following line optional)
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
Require user rbowen
```

Since I am consuming the API from browser side in a page hosted on another domain (the CORS part is already solved), I need to allow certain requests UNauthenticated. These requests are the request which method is "OPTIONS", (preflight as explained here: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests), 
Please, i dont need any info about ajax or any other thing on the browser, I need to know how to do this on apache

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`mod_setenvif`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html) here.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_Method OPTIONS allowed

AuthType Basic 
AuthName "Restricted Files"
# (Following line optional)
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
Require user rbowen
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=allowed
Satisfy any
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing : `Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=allowed
Satisfy any` to get the preflight operate correctly